# SharePoint Site Collection Administrators : Jquery

Tags: rest, jquery

I have a current logged in User Id and through JQuery I want to find that whether the User Id is in site collection admins or not.

```
 $().SPServices({
   operation: "GetUserInfo",
   userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
   completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
   console.log$(xData.responseXML).find("User").attr("IsSiteAdmin"))
   }
});
```

I have used above code but for the normal users its not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

isSiteAdmin gets you Site Admin info, not Site Collection

This might be easier:

```
_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check whether current user is site admin or not.

```
var user = SP.ClientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

var value = user.get_isSiteAdmin ();
```